Jenkins Pull Request failed to clone repo
I am using Docker agent to build the project, configured in Nodes > Clouds, and all the branches work as expected but when I create a PR, it fails with the following error:
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/csf_PR-70@script/ecaff230533314b7e10ef114b9d082e # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/csf_PR-70@script/ecaff230533314b7e10ef114b9d082e
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1073)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:819)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1226)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1309)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:167)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:311)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/csf_PR-70@script/ecaff230533314b7e10ef114b9d082e
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2858)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2762)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2757)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2051)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1071)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/csf_PR-70@script/ecaff230533314b7e10ef114b9d082e"): error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1532062, exit value: 1
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:994)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:506)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2835)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=0, Failed to exec spawn helper: pid: 1532062, exit value: 1
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 19 more
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

and when I look inside the xxxx-scm-key.txt, I see it that the URL is repeated two times
git https://URL.test.git https://URL.test.git

Jenkins Version: 2.452.1

Do you have git installed on the agent that runs this job?

the issue was the latest version of the Jenkins, after revert back to previous LTS started working again
